# JS set minimum date for HTML input date with an IF

Tags: javascript, html, date, input, min

Sorry for my errors but i'm very noob :D
I have to set min date in an input in HTML with a IF:
IF today is > 01-06-2019 set min to today
ELSE set min to 01-06-2019
Can anybody help me? This is my code:

```js
function setMin1() {
 var varData = new Date('01-06-2019'); //dd-mm-YYYY
 var today = new Date();
 today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

 if(varData >= today) {
  document.getElementById('set').min = '01-06-2019';
 }
 else {
  document.getElementById('set').min = '<?php echo date('d-m-Y');?>';
 }
}
```

Comment: Note that '01-06-2019' is not a format supported by ECMAScript and returns an invalid date in some implementations. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work because your passing a string to your input. Your input type's number.
You can use data-type instead.

Comment: Can u explain me how to do this?

Comment: First change your input type from number to date: and set a min, max attribute with the correct format (Y-m-d). See more here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/date

Comment: You should include that comment in the answer.

Comment: "*Your input type's number*". How do you know that? The OP doesn't say what the input type is, I'd expect *date*. The values for an input type date should be in YYYY-MM-DD (aka "ISO") format.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the *setAttribute* method:

```
document.getElementById('set').setAttribute('min', '01-06-2019');
```

Comment: That appears to be an unfortunate munge of jQuery and javascript. [*DOM elements*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) don't have an *attr* method. If you want to set the value of an attribute, use [*setAttribute*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute): `document.getElementById('set').setAttribute('min', '01-06-2019')`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the input is type [*date*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date). You can set the minimum value using the min attribute, e.g.

```
<input type="date" name="someDate" min="2019-01-01">
```

Note that in HTML, an ISO 8601 formatted date will be treated as local, but when parsed by the built–in ECMAScript parser will be treated as UTC.

If you set the value using script, you're relying on the host system's clock being accurate. The value can be set using *setAttribute*:

```js
window.onload = function(){

  var d = new Date();

  // Build ISO 8601 format date string
  var s = d.getFullYear() + '-' + 
          ('0' + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' +
          ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);

  // Set the value of the value and min attributes
  var node = document.querySelector('input');
  if (node) {
    node.setAttribute('min', s);
    node.setAttribute('value', s);
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return false;">
  <input type="date"><br>
  <input type="reset">
</form>
```